# Different backgammon variation name

Tags: backgammon

In my country and in Greece we have three variations of Backgammon. The basic one that is played all around the world and two others. I am looking for the name of on of the two different ones and if it is played anywhere in the world besides my country and Greece.

**Plakoto**

This is mainly the same with backgammon but instead of `hitting` the oponent's checker you `pin` it and it stays there until you move your piece from him. You can also add up to the pinned checker with more of your checkers and your opponent cannot re-pin on top of you.  The setup is also different from the basic backgammon setup as all fifteen checkers are placed in the far edge of the table (left or right depending on the players' preference) and you have to bring all your checkers to the exact opposite one (So more or less if you start from the far right corner you have to bring all your pieces to the close right area and then collect them as with other backgammon games).

Example image

[image]

In the above case I am red. The initial setup can be both in the left side or the right side. It does not matter.

So is there a version of this game in other countries? Does any other country play this game? If so what is called?

Comment: Sounds similar to, but not identical with, *Acey-Deucey*: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acey-deucey. I have never read of variants without *blotting* but it seems like an interesting rule option.

Comment: I think the only commonality between Acey-Deucey and Plakoto is the initial set-up. Also what is blotting?

Comment: This sounds like the variation played in Lebanon, but I don't know what it is called

Comment: I think all three games (portes, plakoto and fevga in Greek, dunno what they're called in other languages) are played all across the Middle East. The Acey-deucy also exists in Greece (so, very possibly in the Middle East as well), where it is known as "assodio" but is not very popular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Plakoto is played elsewhere - in Bulgaria, where it is called Tapa. It seems to be the same game as "Jail", described here: http://www.vitalinfocenter.com/bckgmn/jail.html